# react-native ios app in release mode build is not working ,xcode-12.5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, xcode12.5

debug build is runing in simulator but in release more getting this error , unable run app in release mode and not even able to make build (archive Adhoc build ) .same code was working few days back now facing this issue

```
Could not launch "Appname"
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: failed to get the task for process 790
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "failed to get the task for process 790";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.5.2 (Build 20G95)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-10-11T09:35:29+05:30
```

Comment: What is your question?  ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: on  release adhoc build app crashing . getting above error